# Styling last element with a specific class using css

Tags: html, css, less

I'm trying to style the last div with active class(* element) but my less code styles the last div (x element) when it gets the active class, how can I achieve my intention using less?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="owl-stage">
    <div class="owl-item"></div>
    <div class="owl-item active"></div>
    <div class="owl-item active"></div>
    <div class="owl-item active"></div>*
    <div class="owl-item"></div>
    <div class="owl-item"></div>x
</div>
```

**LESS:**

```
   .owl-item {

            &.active {
                border-right: 1px solid @borderColor;

                &:last-of-type{
                    border-right:none;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

In your case `last-of-type` and `last-child` will always refer to the last element and not the last element with active class. But **if** all the active elements are following each other and you have **3** active elements you can try this :

```css
.owl-item.active + .owl-item.active + .owl-item.active{
 font-size :30px;
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="owl-stage">
    <div class="owl-item">1</div>
    <div class="owl-item active">2</div>
    <div class="owl-item active">3</div>
    <div class="owl-item active">4</div>
    <div class="owl-item">5</div>
    <div class="owl-item">6</div>
</div>
```

But if the number of elements is undefined and there is no particular logic regarding the active class, I think you wil not be able to find a CSS selector for this.

---

*You may consider a JS solution:*

```js
$('.owl-item.active').last().css('color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-stage">
  <div class="owl-item">1</div>
  <div class="owl-item active">2</div>
  <div class="owl-item active">3</div>
  <div class="owl-item">4</div>
  <div class="owl-item  active">5</div>
  <div class="owl-item">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="owl-stage">
    <div class="owl-item active">A</div>
    <div class="owl-item active">B</div>
    <div class="owl-item active">C</div>
    <div class="owl-item active">D</div>
    <div class="owl-item">E</div>
    <div class="owl-item">F</div>
</div>
```

jQuery CODE:

```
$( ".owl-stage .owl-item.active:last" ).css({
    backgroundColor : "yellow"
});
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`last-of-type` is probably the problem because it goes by the element-type, choosing the last `<div>`.  Try `last-child` instead:

```
.owl-item {
    &.active {
        border-right: 1px solid @borderColor;
        &:last-child{ border-right:none; }
    }
}
```

Comment: all the element have the same type here (`div`) so last-child and last-of-type will behave the same